# Angular close error message explicitly by user

Tags: angular, angular5

Hi I have developed web application in Angular 5. I am using alert service for displaying error message. Now I am able to display error message but it disappears after showing the error message. My requirement is error message should not disappear itself and it should close only when user clicks on the cross mark. I have below implementation of alert service class.

```
export class AlertService {
  private messages = new Subject<AlertMessage>();
  private stickyMessages = new Subject<AlertMessage>();
  showMessage(summary: string)
    showMessage(summary: string, detail: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showMessage(summaryAndDetails: string[], summaryAndDetailsSeparator: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showMessage(response: HttpResponseBase, ignoreValue_useNull: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showMessage(data: any, separatorOrDetail?: string, severity?: MessageSeverity) {

        if (!severity)
            severity = MessageSeverity.default;

        if (data instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            data = Utilities.getHttpResponseMessage(data);
            separatorOrDetail = Utilities.captionAndMessageSeparator;
        }

        if (data instanceof Array) {
            for (let message of data) {
                let msgObject = Utilities.splitInTwo(message, separatorOrDetail);

                this.showMessageHelper(msgObject.firstPart, msgObject.secondPart, severity, false);
            }
        }
        else {
            this.showMessageHelper(data, separatorOrDetail, severity, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Showmessagehelper code.

```
 private showMessageHelper(summary: string, detail: string, severity: MessageSeverity, isSticky: boolean) {

    if (isSticky)
            this.stickyMessages.next({ severity: severity, summary: summary, detail: detail });
        else
            this.messages.next({ severity: severity, summary: summary, detail: detail });
    }
    showStickyMessage(summary: string)
    showStickyMessage(summary: string, detail: string, severity: MessageSeverity, error?: any)
    showStickyMessage(summaryAndDetails: string[], summaryAndDetailsSeparator: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showStickyMessage(response: HttpResponseBase, ignoreValue_useNull: string, severity: MessageSeverity)
    showStickyMessage(data: string | string[] | HttpResponseBase, separatorOrDetail?: string, severity?: MessageSeverity, error?: any) {

        if (!severity)
            severity = MessageSeverity.default;

        if (data instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            data = Utilities.getHttpResponseMessage(data);
            separatorOrDetail = Utilities.captionAndMessageSeparator;
        }


        if (data instanceof Array) {
            for (let message of data) {
                let msgObject = Utilities.splitInTwo(message, separatorOrDetail);

                this.showMessageHelper(msgObject.firstPart, msgObject.secondPart, severity, true);
            }
        }
        else {

            if (error) {

                let msg = `Severity: "${MessageSeverity[severity]}", Summary: "${data}", Detail: "${separatorOrDetail}", Error: "${Utilities.safeStringify(error)}"`;

                switch (severity) {
                    case MessageSeverity.default:
                        this.logInfo(msg);
                        break;
                    case MessageSeverity.info:
                        this.logInfo(msg);
                        break;
                    case MessageSeverity.success:
                        this.logMessage(msg);
                        break;
                    case MessageSeverity.error:
                        this.logError(msg);
                        break;
                    case MessageSeverity.warn:
                        this.logWarning(msg);
                        break;
                    case MessageSeverity.wait:
                        this.logTrace(msg);
                        break;
                }
            }

            this.showMessageHelper(data, separatorOrDetail, severity, true);
        }
    }
```

I am using alert service as below in my components.

```
 this.alertService.showMessage(caption, message, MessageSeverity.error);
```

Above error message display error message in top right corner(red color with cross mark).  This error message disappears may be after 2 seconds. I want error message to close only when user closes on cross mark. Can someone tell me how to make this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: add code for showMessageHelper in your question so it will be easy to guess where is problem exists

Comment: Hi, I have added code for this.

Comment: Are you using any library to display error message. seems like toast msg?

Comment: put code for logInfo()

Comment: logInfo(msg) {
        console.info(msg);
    } I use it for loginfo.